# yii 1.1 CHtmlPurifier allowed elements

Tags: php, yii, htmlpurifier

How to allowed header/footer html element in CHtmlPurifier in yii?

I tried this code but given error.

```
$CHtmlPurifier = new CHtmlPurifier();
$CHtmlPurifier->options = array('HTML.AllowedElements' => ['header'=>true]);
echo $CHtmlPurifier->purify('<header>Testing</header>');
```

I spent some time on searching for some override class to allow this but couldn't found.

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 1):

Since `header` is HTML5 tag you need to customize HtmlPurifier to use it.

See the ["Customize!"](http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-customize.html) documentation.